# Android EditText setText not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to setText of edittext using java but it is not working and force closing my application, though i am not sure why

Java Code

```
EditText UserProfileFirstName;
UserProfileFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userFirstName);
UserProfileFirstName.setText("John");
```

Xml

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/userFirstName"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:textSize="22sp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
   android:hint="First Name"
   android:ems="10"
  />
```

LogCat Error

```
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unext.unextlibrary/com.unext.unextlibrary.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unext.unextlibrary/com.unext.unextlibrary.UserProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unext.unextlibrary/com.unext.unextlibrary.UserProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at com.unext.unextlibrary.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:105)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     ... 11 more
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at com.unext.unextlibrary.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:57)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        01-23 09:32:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(4101):     ... 21 more
```

I searched on google and also saw SO answers but nothing seems to be working for me

Comment: post your logcat error here

Comment: anyone can explain reason for -1 ??

Comment: People will downvote your question when they feel it's not clear what the problem is, or you've not posted enough information about the problem

Comment: hey its working fine man ...can u put your code

Comment: most probably because, you dint posted StackTrace in starting, Try to be more clear when u post ur question.

Comment: And even though the question was closed, it was my exact situation and I understood it perfectly. About to try accepted answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add 
`setContentView(R.layout.LAYOUTNAME);` in oncreate,  before you try to get view by

`UserProfileFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userFirstName);`

// here `LAYOUTNAME` is your layout's name where you define this `edittext`

Comment: Gosh that was the error, dude thanks a lot